# Fox & Hound or regular FT8 for ARRL International Digital Contest?

Tags: contest, ft8

So I'm thinking about casually working the ARRL Int'l Digital contest this weekend to try to pick up (hopefully they'll confirm!) a couple of new DCXX entities so I can get my DXCC (almost there).

While I have done some SSB contesting I have never done an FT8 contest.  I have gotting the N3FJP contest logger for the event set up and talking with JTAlert so that's all good.

What I am wondering, though, is if FT8 contests (and this contest in particular) happen in "regular" mode or in fox & hound mode.  I did read the ARRL's rule for this contest and the sample exchange does look like a "regular" exchange.  But since the rules say all you have to do is exchange grid squares maybe fox & hound is allowed too?

I wouldn't be doing fox myself but I am wondering if I should make sure to understand hound before the contest starts or if I don't have to worry about it for this.

Comment: For those following along at home, I found https://www.onallbands.com/using-the-ft8-dxpedition-mode-a-k-a-fox-and-hound%EF%BB%BF/ for starters that gives a little more insight/context into this "fox & hound" mode.

Answer (score 1):

Regular (please).

Fox and Hound mode is intended for the scenario where *everybody* on frequency (the "hounds") are working *one* station (the fox). It's optimized to max out the fox's QSO rate so that as many hounds as possible can get through to a DXpedition. But there isn't enough room in the FT8 sub-band for more than a couple stations to "run a frequency"; instead, everyone works everyone. Enabling fox mode in a digi contest would make a mess and be a generally unfriendly thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the answer is more like "neither".  As the other answer says, Fox/Hound should **not** be used for this contest.  But "regular" shouldn't be used either.

What should be used is (what WSJT-X calls it anyways) the "WW Digi Contest" special operating activity.  You can find it on the "Advanced" tab of the "Settings" page if you are using WSJT-X.  (I don't know what JTDX uses since I don't use that one).

When this mode is activated WSJT-X will use a different, abbreviated set of messages. (The ARRL rules document for the contest shows what those are in the simple exchange that it listed.)